# Loop within a Loop PHP

Tags: php, while-loop

Ok, this is my first time using Stack so I apologize in advance for anything I do incorrectly.

The Situation:
        I have a class project to rewrite HTML code in PHP. Here is a snippet of the HTML code.

```
<div class="col-small-6 col-med-6 col-lg-4 albumContainer">
    <img src="_images/elephant_king_cover_240x240.png" alt="">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h2 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">Elephant King</a></h2>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ol>
                        <li>Elephant King</li>
                        <li>Joy &amp; Sorrow</li>
                        <li>Traverse</li>
                        <li>Tres Capos</li>
                        <li>Timepiece</li>
                        <li>Adventures in Sawyerland</li>
                        <li>Be Still</li>
                        <li>Overtime</li>
                        <li>Bongolo</li>
                        <li>Coronation</li>
                        <li>Anchor</li>
                    </ol>
                    <h3>available at:</h3>
                    <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/elephant-king/id512331651">iTunes</a>
                    <a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007G3SEFW" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Amazon</a>
                    <a href="http://store.whatarerecords.com/collections/trace-bundy/products/trace-bundy-elephant-king-1">United Interests</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
</div><!-- end albumContainer -->
```

The structure repeats with different content.

The Problem:
        When I run my SQl/PHP I am getting all of the information I am asking for, but it is not rendering properly. I get all of my information over and over again for as many different song titles there are (the ordered list).
I want everything to run one time for each section and for the song titles to be the content for the accordion. Here is the SQL/PHP code I have been messing around with.

```
<?php 
require('mysqli_connect_remote.php');
$q = "SELECT Album_Art, Concat(Title, ' ', Release_Date) AS Title, destination, direction, Songs.Name FROM Albums Inner JOIN Songs ON Albums.Album_id=Songs.Album_id ";
$result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $q);
if ($result){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        echo '<div class="col-small-6 col-med-6 col-lg-4 albumContainer">';
        echo '<img src=' . $row['Album_Art'] . 'alt="">';           
        echo '<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">';
        echo '<div class="panel panel-default">';
        echo '<div class="panel-heading">';
        echo '<h2 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href=' . $row['direction'] . '>' . $row['Title'] . '</a></h2></div><div id=' . $row['destination'] . ' class="panel-collapse collapse"><div class="panel-body">';

        echo '<ol> <li>' . $row['Name'] . '</li> </ol> </div></div></div></div></div>';
    }
    // <h3>available at:</h3>
    // <a href=' . ['Location'] . '>iTunes</a>
    // <a href=' . ['Location2'] . '>Amazon</a>
    // <a href=' . ['Location3'] . '>United Interests</a>
    // ';}

    mysqli_free_result ($result); 
} else { 
    echo '<p class="error">The current users could not be retrieved. We apologize for any inconvenience.</p>';
    echo '<p>' . mysqli_error($dbcon) . '<br><br />Query: ' . $q . '</p>';
} 

mysqli_close($dbcon); 
?>
```

Any insights on how to make this work for me would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you're doing loops in loops, or if-statements in loops, or loops in if-statements, indent better to where its clear what's in what. Sounds trivial, but it makes all the difference in the world.

And I would suggest losing the Egyptian brackets. You know, the ones that look like someone walking like an Egyptian.  That is, start putting opening brackets on a new line so the opening and closing brackets line up which makes it easy to see when a bracket is missing.

I have re-indented your code without changing anything:

```
if ($result)
{
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        echo '<div class="col-small-6 col-med-6 col-lg-4 albumContainer">';
        echo '<img src=' . $row['Album_Art'] . 'alt="">';           
        echo '<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">';
        echo '<div class="panel panel-default">';
        echo '<div class="panel-heading">';
        echo '<h2 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href=' . $row['direction'] . '>' . $row['Title'] . '</a></h2></div><div id=' . $row['destination'] . ' class="panel-collapse collapse"><div class="panel-body">';

        echo '<ol> <li>' . $row['Name'] . '</li> </ol> </div></div></div></div></div>';
    }


    /*<h3>available at:</h3>
    <a href=' . ['Location'] . '>iTunes</a>
    <a href=' . ['Location2'] . '>Amazon</a>
    <a href=' . ['Location3'] . '>United Interests</a>
    ';}*/


    mysqli_free_result ($result); 
}
else 
{
    echo '<p class="error">The current users could not be retrieved. We apologize for any inconvenience.</p>';
    echo '<p>' . mysqli_error($dbcon) . '<br><br />Query: ' . $q . '</p>';
} 
mysqli_close($dbcon); 
?>
```

Now you can actually see what's going on.   Initially when I re-indented the first time I missed one of your closing brackets that was hiding at the end of a long long line and thought you were missing the closing bracket of the loop.

And it seems the problem is actually with your SQL query. Throwing a `distinct` in there might solve it:

```
$q = "SELECT DISTINCT Album_Art, Concat(Title, ' ', Release_Date) AS Title, destination, direction, Songs.Name FROM Albums Inner JOIN Songs ON Albums.Album_id=Songs.Album_id ";
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, the code looks much cleaner now, however Im still not getting the accordion to work @developerwjk

Comment: @ChristopherClear, This is supposed to be an accordion? I didn't see any mention of that. You should look into some jquery accordion examples: http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/